# SQL Conditional WHERE Using IN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a rough time getting this syntax correct and cannot figure out how to correctly write this.

I have a stored procedure with some joins and the where clause is like this:

```
WHERE
    [Column1] = (SELECT Source FROM @CurrentTransition) AND
    [Column2] = (SELECT Target FROM @CurrentTransition) AND
    [IsDeprecated] = 0 AND
    sbl.StratId is null AND
    std.StratId is null AND
    CASE WHEN s.StratTimeBiasId <> NULL THEN s.StratTimeBiasId IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGetValidTimeBiases(CAST(@datetime AS TIME)))
```

The error is simply `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IN'.`

The `fnGetValidTimeBiases` function just returns a list of the `Id` values from the table that the `StratTimeBiasId` is the foreign key to.

I only want that particular join to be used when there is actually a value in the `StratTimeBiasId` column.

Comment: You can get rid of the check for NULL altogether.  It is extraneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what a CASE statement is for. Use simple boolean logic instead:

```
AND (s.StratTimeBiasId IS NULL OR s.StartTimeBiasId IS NOT NULL AND s.StratTimeBiasId IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGetValidTimeBiases(CAST(@datetime AS TIME))))
```

The above will match anything where `s.StratTimeBiasId` has a NULL value OR where its value is in the results of that function (I assume the function only returns a single column? If not, that's going to throw an error).

Related note: `=` and `<>` aren't the correct operators when dealing with NULL. If you want to test if a column's value is (not) null you need to use `column IS (NOT) NULL`.

Comment: i think the `IN` will be executed when you use it with OR. to avoid this, i recommend you use `s.StratTimeBiasId IS NOT NULL AND s.StratTimeBiasId IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGetValidTimeBiases(CAST(@datetime AS TIME))))`

Comment: @BrettSchneider I tend to forget that SQL doesn't necessarily short circuit OR conditions. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: If it is IN, then it is not NULL, so the NULL check is not needed.

Comment: @SQLDBA I disagree, that's a totally different query and not what they want. They want anything where the value is null or, if it does have a value, where that value is IN the result of the subquery.

Comment: "...when there is actually a value in the StratTimeBiasId column."  I read this statement as meaning it is not null.

Comment: @SQLDBA I read it differently, and since my answer was accepted and the person asking the question said it was "exactly what was needed", I'm leaning towards saying my interpretation of the question was correct. Essentially: If there is a value, check if it's in this set of values. If there is not a value, bring back the row without doing the check because I still care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE
    [Column1] = (SELECT Source FROM @CurrentTransition) AND
    [Column2] = (SELECT Target FROM @CurrentTransition) AND
    [IsDeprecated] = 0 AND
    sbl.StratId is null AND
    std.StratId is null AND
    s.StratTimeBiasId IS NULL OR s.StratTimeBiasId IN (dbo.fnGetValidTimeBiases(CAST(@datetime AS TIME)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured this out already....

```
WHERE
[Column1] = (SELECT Source FROM @CurrentTransition) AND
[Column2] = (SELECT Target FROM @CurrentTransition) AND
[IsDeprecated] = 0 AND
sbl.StratId is null AND
std.StratId is null AND
s.StratTimeBiasId IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.fnGetValidTimeBiases(CAST(@datetime AS TIME)))
```